# PHP Foreach Loop Efficiency

Tags: php, arrays

I am using a `foreach` loop within PHP similar to this:

```
foreach ($class->getAttributes() as $attribute) {
// Work
}
```

Concerning efficiency, is it better to have a `$attributes = $class->getAttributes();` statement outside the `foreach` loop and iterate over the `$attributes` variable? Or is the `$class->getAttributes()` statement only getting called once inside the `foreach` declaration at the beginning?

(I realize this might not be a *big* efficiency concern in this case, but I would like to know the principle for this and other larger cases)

Thanks,

Steve

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using `$class->getAttributes()` outside of the `foreach` loop and using a temporary variable, or keeping it like you wrote should not change anything about performances : **it will still be evaluated only once**.

And here is an example that proves it :

```
function get_array() {
    echo 'function called !<br />';
    return array(
        'first' => 123,
        'second' => 456,
        'last' => 789, 
    );
}
foreach (get_array() as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key : $value<br />";
}
```

*I am using a function and not a method of a class, to get a shorter example, but the principle would be the same with a class+method.*

And calling this portion of code gives the following output :

```
function called !
first : 123
second : 456
last : 789
```

i.e. the `get_array()` function is only called once, at the beginning of the `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 2):

[`foreach`](http://php.net/foreach) operates on a copy internally:

> **Note:** Unless the array is referenced, `foreach` operates on a copy of the specified array and not the array itself. […]

So it doesn’t make any difference in your case. `$class->getAttributes()` is only called once to retrieve the array.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested, but I'd think that doing something like this:

```
$attributes = $class->getAttributes();
foreach($attributes as $attribute)
{

}
```

Is more readable, and you can get to the attributes after the foreach has conclude if you need to.

However, in a more direct response to your question, `getAttributes()` will only be called once in either case.

Comment: +1 for the convenience of accessing `$attributes` outside of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, the function in your example is only called once.

The case in which pre-evaluating can make a difference is for loops.

```
$str = 'abcdefghijklmnop';

//strlen will be called on every iteration
for($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); $i++);

//strlen will only be called once
$len = strlen($str);
for($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++);
```